# google colabで学習データセットを自動的に読み込ませる方法は？

Tags: python, google-cloud, google-colaboratory

例えばローカルでデータを読み込むときは

```
def dataLoadBatch(self, num_samples):
    X=[]
    Y=[]
    for h in range(0, num_samples):
        I = io.imread("data/images/salMap_{:05d}.jpg".format(h))
        X.append(I)
        labels = io.imread("data/salMap/salMap_{:05d}.jpg".format(h))[:,:,0]
```

な感じで連番であるフォルダのデータを読み込ませるわけですが、colabでこれやるためにわざわざdriveにデータをアップロードするのもダルい感じがします。colabでローカルのデータセットを上記の様に連続付番で自動的に読み込ませるにはどうすれば良いでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

Colaboratory の公式サンプル ["External data: Drive, Sheets, and Cloud Storage"](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb) が参考になります。

Google Drive を使わずにローカルからファイルをアップロードする場合、以下のを実行するとファイル選択ダイアログから複数ファイルをアップロードすることができます。

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
```

アップロードしたファイルたちは同時に Colaboratory のカレントディレクトリに保存されるので、後はローカルと同様に扱うことができます。

アップロードされたファイルの一覧が確認したければ、`!ls` すれば良いです。

ただしこの方法でアップロードすると、アップロードされたファイルたちを後からディレクトリ分けするなどの操作が面倒くさくなります。このため個人的にはデータセットを Google Drive 上に置き、[PyDrive や google-drive-ocamlfuse 経由でアクセスする](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47744131/5989200)方が管理はしやすいと思います。Qiita の「[google Colaboratoryでファイルを読み込む方法](https://qiita.com/uni-3/items/201aaa2708260cc790b8)」も参考になります。